# SetPrecision with indexed variables

Tags: formatting

I have an expression as below:

```
Equations = 2.0799361919940695` x[1] + 3.3534325557330327` x[1]^2 - 
   4.335179297091139` x[1] x[2] + 1.1989715511881491` x[2]^2 - 
   3.766597877399148` x[1] x[3] - 0.33254815073371535` x[2] x[3] + 
   1.9050048836042945` x[3]^2 + 1.1386715715291826` x[1] x[4] + 
   2.802846492104668` x[2] x[4] - 0.6210244597295915` x[3] x[4] + 
   4.943369095158792` x[4]^2
```

I want to write it in an output file. So I use the below code:

```
removebracketvar[x_] := 
  StringReplace[
   StringReplace[
    ToString[x], {"[" -> "", "]" -> "", "," -> "", "*^" -> "e", 
     ".*" -> ".0*"}], Whitespace -> ""];
SetDirectory["C:\\folder"];
WriteString["eqfile.txt", 
  removebracketvar[
   ToString[Equations , InputForm, NumberMarks -> False]] ];
Close["eqfile.txt"]
```

The slight problem with the code for me is that it inserts the floating point numbers up to 16 digits of precision. I just want them to around up to 10 digits of precision.
When I use `SetPrecision[Equations,10]`, it weirdly changes `x[1]` etc. to `x[1.0000000]`, etc.! I want to leave the variables as they are but want to change the floating points to less number of digits after the decimal point. What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: `SetPrecision` is *not* meant to be used for display purposes. You should use it only when you actually want to perform calculations at a specific precision. Otherwise, use `NumberForm` or something similar.

Comment: @OleksandrR., if I use NumberForm[Equations,6], then it also prints out 'NumberForm' in the front of the expression and '6' at the end of the expression in the output file!

Comment: Here is code I have used for similar purposes. `resetPrecision[(a_List | a_Plus), prec_] := 
 Map[resetPrecision[#, prec] &, a]
resetPrecision[a_?NumberQ*b_., prec_] := SetPrecision[a, prec]*b
resetPrecision[a_, prec_] := a`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, Excellent! That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - please post this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is code I have used for similar purposes.

```
resetPrecision[(a_List | a_Plus), prec_] :=
    Map[resetPrecision[#, prec] &, a]

resetPrecision[a_?NumberQ*b_., prec_] := SetPrecision[a, prec]*b

resetPrecision[a_, prec_] := a
```

That example:

```
equations = 
  2.0799361919940695` x[1] + 3.3534325557330327` x[1]^2 - 
   4.335179297091139` x[1] x[2] + 1.1989715511881491` x[2]^2 - 
   3.766597877399148` x[1] x[3] - 0.33254815073371535` x[2] x[3] + 
   1.9050048836042945` x[3]^2 + 1.1386715715291826` x[1] x[4] + 
   2.802846492104668` x[2] x[4] - 0.6210244597295915` x[3] x[4] + 
   4.943369095158792` x[4]^2;

resetPrecision[equations, 10]

(* Out[3]= 2.079936192 x[1] + 3.353432556 x[1]^2 - 4.335179297 x[1] x[2] + 
 1.198971551 x[2]^2 - 3.766597877 x[1] x[3] - 
 0.3325481507 x[2] x[3] + 1.905004884 x[3]^2 + 
 1.138671572 x[1] x[4] + 2.802846492 x[2] x[4] - 
 0.6210244597 x[3] x[4] + 4.943369095 x[4]^2 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set [`NHoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NHoldAll.html) or [`NHoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NHoldFirst.html) on `x` and it will protect the index.

```
expr = 3.766597877399148` x[1] x[3] - 0.33254815073371535` x[2] x[3];

SetAttributes[x, NHoldAll];

SetPrecision[expr, 3]

SetPrecision[expr, 22]
```

> ```
> 3.77 x[1] x[3] - 0.333 x[2] x[3]
>
> 3.766597877399147975552 x[1] x[3] - 0.3325481507337153530557 x[2] x[3]
> ```