# Apply N only outside a certain function

Tags: numerics, pattern-matching, attributes

```
1 + f[1] // N
```

gives

```
 1. + f[1.]
```

I don't want the argument of `f` evaluated by N; I want to get

```
1. + f[1]
```

instead.

In general, there is a large algebraic expression containing some subexpressions of type `f[__]`. `N` should not be applied inside `f`. `N` should be applied only outside.

Mapping `N` at a certain level only is **not** OK, since the tree structure of expression is not know in advance.

One possible trick is

```
1 + f[1] /. x_f :> 1. x + 0.
```

It would be good to know other options.

Comment: Related: [(24318)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24318/121)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best option then is to bestow the attribute `NHold` on the head `f`.

```
In[2]:= SetAttributes[f, NHoldAll]

In[3]:= 2 + f[Sqrt[2] + 1] // N

Out[3]= 2. + f[1 + Sqrt[2]]
```

Comment: In fact there is an example given in the documentation of `N` which is similar to this one :)