# How to approximate only number but not the numeric indices in an equation?

Tags: approximation

I need to solve a system of equations. It would be too long to solve it exactly, so I need to approximate by numbers the coefficients.

The problem is the following :

```
In[51]:= N[1/3*gamma[1], 20]

Out[51]= 0.33333333333333333333 gamma[1.0000000000000000000]
```

As you can see, the indice 1 in gamma[1] is also approximated. But I don't want the indices to be approximated. (In fact I'm solving a linear system of equations and this behavior can be a little problematic).

How to tell mathematica to only approximate coefficients of the equations but not indices inside brackets ?

Comment: Can the argument of `gamma` be Rational? if not, you can use this: `N[expr] /. gamma[x_] :> gamma[Floor[x]]`.

Comment: You can use one of [`NHold...` attributes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ControllingNumericalEvaluation.html). Related: [Apply N only outside a certain function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29486/14303), [Is there a way to prevent N from being applied to all parts of an expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124927/14303)

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by approximate unity, let it infect your exact coefficients.

```
1`20 1/3*gamma[1]
(* 0.33333333333333333333 gamma[1] *)
```

Depending on how complicated your expressions are, you might need to use `Expand` or other formula manipulation functions to push the approximate constant into the deep corners.

Answer (score 1):

```
keep[head_] := Not[SameQ[{}, If[System`Private`HasImmediateValueQ[head], 0, {}],
           DownValues[head], UpValues[head], FormatValues[head], Attributes[head],
      Options[head], If[System`Private`HasAnyCodesQ[head], 0, {}], SubValues[head]]]

expr = 1/3*gamma[1];

pos = Position[expr, _?NumericQ];
which = And @@ Extract[expr, Append[#, 0] & /@ #, keep] & /@
           Map[Table[#[[;; i]], {i, 0, Length[#] - 1}] &, pos];
MapAt[N, expr, Pick[pos, which]]
```

> 0.33333333 gamma[1]

Probably there are some of the "values" in `keep` which aren't necessary in your cases. I think `Attributes` and `Options`.