# Selectively changing precision while leaving integers and rationals unchanged

Tags: expression-manipulation, precision-and-accuracy

I didn't find an answer to this question on the site, but as I was writing up my question, I figured out how to do it, so I thought I should post it and answer my own question so that others can benefit from it.

This is a similar question to the [one found here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24318/setprecision-with-indexed-variables), but I am looking for a more general solution.

Suppose I have a complicated structure, which can include functions (some defined, some not), lists (sometimes nested), replacement rules, Quantity expressions, and so on. I need to modify the precision of any number that is *not* an integer or a ratio of integers, but want to leave the integers and ratios unchanged. How can I do that? Examples:

```
rxn[a + 1/2 b, 2 c + d, Quantity[1.03*10^-2, "Molar"]]

{x[1] -> Quantity[2.4*10^3, "Molar"], x[2] -> 0, 
          x[3] -> Quantity[16.2, "Moles"], x[4] -> 3.2}
```

Here I want to change the precision of the three values within the Quantity statements and the 3.2, but nothing else.

Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Replace[exp1, a:(_Real|_Complex) :> SetPrecision[a, 10], All]
```